# Understanding which and how headers are being set

Tags: c#, soap, http-headers, postman, soapui

We have some code here given by somebody else and we can't tell what is going on:

```
var headerContent = new ApiMessageHeaderContract { PlatformType = PlatformType, SystemName = this.systemName };
                var header = new MessageHeader<ApiMessageHeaderContract>(headerContent);
                var messageHeader = header.GetUntypedHeader("Authentication", "urn:exOrganisation:core");
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(messageHeader);
```

The `ApiMessageHeaderContract` class is defined as follow:

```
internal class ApiMessageHeaderContract
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the authentication token.
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the system name.
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string SystemName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the platform type.
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string PlatformType { get; set; }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on here? I think this code is setting a value into a header but I can't tell which one. Ideally, what I'm trying to do here is to replicate the request in SoapUI or Postman and currently I'm stuck with this authentication.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler which will show the entire http message.  If using HTTPS then temporarily use HTTP so you can see the request without encryption.

Comment: Mmm, nice idea I'll give that a go. Thanks

Comment: good idea, however computer said no - https is required - probably something about the ssl ceritificate it's applying

Comment: Compare headers in first request between Postman and c#.   Often the the User Agent needs to be added.  If fails after 30 seconds you are trying to go to a proxy and can't find proxy.  The setting proxy in client to null.